# Populate an Object property with JSON data

Tags: javascript

I am struggling to get an object populated with pre-existing data. Similar questions exist, yet I could not find my specific case, namely to populate the property of a property within in object.

I want to display a number of hexes with a [hexmap library](https://open-innovations.github.io/oi.hexmap.js/). Quite straightforward:

**hex.js**

```
hex = new OI.hexmap(document.getElementById('hexmap'), {
  hexjson: {
    layout: 'even-q',
    hexes: {
        // A: { n: '0,1', q: 0, r: 1 },
        // B: { n: '1,1', q: 1, r: 1 },
        // C: { n: '2,1', q: 2, r: 1 },
        // D: { n: '0,2', q: 0, r: 2 },
        // E: { n: '1,2', q: 1, r: 2 },
        // F: { n: '2,2', q: 2, r: 2 },
        // G: { n: '1,3', q: 1, r: 3 },
    },
  },
})
```

The commented lines in `hex.hexjson.hexes` demonstrate working sample data.

By means of PHP I generated a JSON string which contains the necessary data. A shortened version of its output in a HTML/TWIG file is this:

**map_data.html**

```
<div class="js-map"
  data-map="1: {n: '1', q: 0, r: 0},2: {n: '2', q: 1, r: 0},3: {n: '3', q: 2, r: 0}"
></div>
```

If I copy this generated string into `hex.hexjson.hexes` (in the `hex.js` file) manually, all hexes are displayed as intended. I want this to happen via JS, of course.

In the JS file I therefore grab the JSON string like so:

**hex.js**

```
var map = $('.js-map').data('map')
```

`map` now contains the JSON string from the `map_data.html` file.

I now get stuck in how I can insert `map` into `hex.hexjson.hexes`.

I have tried:

**hex.js**

```
hex = new OI.hexmap(document.getElementById('hexmap'), {
...
})

hex['hexjson']['hexes'] = JSON.parse(map)
```

This leads to this error:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 1`

I also tried this:

**hex.js**

```
hex = new OI.hexmap(document.getElementById('hexmap'), {
...
})

hex['hexjson']['hexes'].push(map);
```

This leads to another error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hexes')`

How do I get my JSON string into the `hexes` property of the `hex` object?

Note: I have jQuery available, if that is of any assistance.

Comment: What is the exact string stored in `map`?

Comment: According to `console.log(map)` it is `1: {n: '1', q: 0, r: 0},2: {n: '2', q: 1, r: 0},3: {n: '3', q: 2, r: 0},`. It is, of course, much longer than this. This is merely the first few entries.

Comment: this is not a valid JSON string - so no wonder you get errors, when you want to parse it.

Comment: True, actually. I don't seem to see the forest for the trees correctly. Been working on this for too long... :-) The sample data in `.hexes` is also not valid JSON, then. Yet, it works just fine (so does the generated string). Maybe I must rephrase the question. The point seems in the end how I can get the string into the appropriate place.

Comment: added an answer - I parsed the string into an array of objects (based on the keys that seemed logical), but if you want a different shape, then tweaking the custom parser can do anything.

Comment: If you would write `data-map="{...}"` then it's valid json and your first approach would work

Comment: @JozefDochan Great point. I just tested it by fixing the string, manually replacing `hexes: { ... }` with `hexes {"1": {"n": "1", "q": 0, "r": 0},"2": {"n": "2", "q": 1, "r": 0},"3": {"n": "3", "q": 2, "r": 0}` . It works. My code does not, though. :-) `hex['hexjson']['hexes'] = JSON.parse(map)` throws this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'hexes')`. I have tried to define (`let`) `hexes` somehow, but keep failing.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid JSON:

```js
const map = "1: {n: '1', q: 0, r: 0},2: {n: '2', q: 1, r: 0},3: {n: '3', q: 2, r: 0}"

console.log(JSON.parse(map)) // expected error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 1
```

You can try to parse it differently, though (not necessarily efficient, but does the job):

```js
const map = "1: {n: '1', q: 0, r: 0},2: {n: '2', q: 1, r: 0},3: {n: '3', q: 2, r: 0}"

const hex = {
  hexjson: {
    hexes: null
  }
}

const ifNum = (val) => isNaN(Number(val)) ?
  val.replace(/\'/g, "") :
  Number(val)

const customKeyValParser = (str) => str
  .split(": ")
  .map(ifNum)

const customObjParser = (str) => Object.fromEntries(str
  .replace(/[{}]/g, "")
  .split(", ")
  .map(customKeyValParser)
)

const customParser = (str) => str
  .replace(/.: {/g, "{")
  .replace(/},{/g, "}##{") // creating a unique-like delimiter
  .split("##")
  .map(customObjParser)

const parsed = customParser(map)

hex['hexjson']['hexes'] = parsed // hex.hexjson.hexes would also be OK

console.log("hex", hex)
```

When you get a value without error, then adding it to the object is only `hex.hexjson.hexes = yourvalue`.

#### OR TRY THIS

This yields an object with the numbers as keys:

```js
const map = "1: {n: '1', q: 0, r: 0},2: {n: '2', q: 1, r: 0},3: {n: '3', q: 2, r: 0}"

const customParser = (str) => str
  .replace(/\'/g, ("\"")) // replacing single quotes with double quotes
  .replace(/(.): /g, ("\"$1\": ")) // adding double quotes around the keys

const finalStr = `{${customParser(map)}}` // wrapping the parsed string in {}

const parsed = JSON.parse(finalStr)

const hex = {
  hexjson: {
    hexes: null,
  }
}

hex.hexjson.hexes = parsed
console.log(hex)
```

Comment: Interesting approaches. Definitely helps clear my head some. The first one gives me the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'hexes')` The second one has error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Expected double-quoted property name in JSON at position 289`. Position 289 is here: `const parsed = JSON.^ parse(finalStr)`

Comment: @Charles the parsers were created based on the example you set in your question - the errors come from cases that were not represented in the example. Sorry, but without knowing the cases (including edge cases) a string parser won't be perfect (errors are expected).

Comment: @Charles the first error you mention doesn't seem to be in the scope of string parsing - the attribute probably does not exist on the object. Check if it's there, before trying to set it to a value (and if it's not there, simply add it)

Comment: @Charles the second error is about correct JSON - in a JSON string there can be only double quotes around the keys (required) or string values (required). No single quotes are allowed (only in the string values themselves).

Comment: @Charles but the parser I provided are easy to update to handle these cases - they are broken down into steps (functions), so it's simple to just add a new "rule" to them.

Comment: Mistake on my part. Misclicked. Position 289 is the end of the complete string: `{"n": "625", "q": 24, "r": 24}}`

Comment: The first error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'hexes')` is in scope. In my initial post the property `hexes` is shown to be in the `hex` object. Yet no matter what I do I always get `undefined` there when attempting to access it.